# Software to open or convert old Paint Shop Pro (*.psp) graphic files on GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, image-conversion, image, inkscape, gimp

I have some old Paint Shop Pro files (*.psp) which I had created more than 20 years ago. I would like to open them on Linux, or at least convert them into some modern non-proprietary graphical file format (like svg). I also don't have any PSP license anymore. I have already tried to open the images using GIMP but unfortunately I get the following error message "Paint Shop Pro image Message. Unsupported layer type Vector (Layer 1)". Inkscape was also not able to open them.

Any idea which program or script I could use?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to import images with [GIMP plugin](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/blob/master/plug-ins/common/file-psp.c) ? The link give you a page to the site where the sources exists. You can download source from there and build the GIMP module. You may also find this module in the package repository of your distribution.

The easiest tool I know to convert psp files is [Irfanview](https://www.irfanview.com/); unfortunately it's only available on Windows.

IrfanView is Freeware for non-commercial use. You may use it on a Windows PC to convert psp file to a format readable by Inkscape or GIMP.

Answer (score 0):

[XnView MP](https://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/) is able to open PSP files. From there you can save as other formats.

(With XnView version 0.98.4 (there are newer versions) on Kubuntu 20.04 I was able to open PSP file format version 7.0 that GIMP did not support.)